# Using list.index with duplicate items inside the list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm working in python 3.4

I have a problem with a piece in a program that is supposed to return all nested lists which first value is the biggest value.

I first tried the following code:

```
L = [['5','4','3'], ['23', '40', '8'], ['33', '24', '29'], ['33', '24', '29'],
 ['13', '66', '54'], ['5', '4', '3']]

BigNumFirst = []
for i in L:
if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
    BigNumFirst.append(L.index(i))
print(BigNumFirst)
```

And got the following output:

```
[0, 2, 2, 0]
```

As you can see the problem is that list.index() only returns the first matching nested list, so the index for the duplicate nested lists is not correct. I want the output to be:

```
[0, 2, 3, 5]
```

I can't figure out how I should solve this, at first I thought I could just add a variable that kept count of how many of a duplicate that existed inside of

```
BigNumFirst
```

but that of course only works if there's only one nested list with duplicates as my attempt showed:

```
BigNumFirst = []
NumbOfCopys=0
for i in L:
if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
    if L.index(i) in BigNumFirst:
        NumbOfCopys+=1
    BigNumFirst.append(L.index(i)+NumbOfCopys)

print(BigNumFirst)
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 2]
```

As you can see the last number is still wrong. So, how would I do to make my program "know" what index a nested list has, even if it is a duplicate of a previous nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(L) if max(j)==j[0]]
[0, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Is that code all that's needed to render the correct output? When I runs it in the shell nothing happens. I forgot to say, I'm in Python 3.4

Comment: what you mean by nothing happens ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very good at this. It worked for me when I created a new list called L2 and added L2.append(i) in the beggining instead of just i. Maybe that's what you meant but as I said I'm kinda rubbish- Thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome ...! i thought you have omit something ! ;)